# Prevent Upload before POST if file is too large with PHP

Tags: php, post, file-upload

This script is to upload an image file, smaller than 2MB. I want to check the file size before the file is uploaded. Because what I tried is showing this warning, if the upload file size is more than 20MB:

> Warning: POST Content-Length of 20402819 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0

I don't want to change the php.ini file to increase the max upload file size... I wan't it not to upload more than 2MB.

Please help....

```
if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
  $errors= array();
  $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
  $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
  $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
  $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];
  $file_ext= explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name']);
  $file_ext= $file_ext[count($file_ext)-1];
  $file_ext= strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));
  
  $extensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");
  
  if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions)=== false){
     $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
  }
  
  if($file_size > 2097152){
    $errors[] = 'File size must not exceed 2 MB.';
  }
  if(!empty($filename)){
    $errors[] = "Please choose a file before you upload.";
  }
  
  if(empty($errors)==true){
    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/" . $file_name);
    $file_location = "uploads/" . $file_name;
    submitFile($file_location);
  }else{
     print_r($errors);
  }
```

}

Comment: This is nothing you can do in php. You need to do that on the client side, so using javascript to check the request _before_ it is even sent.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what (if any) JS framework you are using, but jQuery can do this. You need to override your submit event handler on the client side, and do the following:

```
<input type="file" id="file-select" />
//you might need additional properties on ^
const upload_limit = 2; //MB
jQuery("#file-select").on('change', function() {
    const size = this.files[0].size / 1024 / 1024;
    if (size < upload_limit) { return true; }
    else { alert("File size is " + size + " MB, please select a smaller file."); return false;}
}
```

This is just an example, in reality it's better to add the function as part of the submit event, and prevent submission if the output of the function is false (and or your other validations).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you've got to set an entry in the `php.ini` file:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize

A JavaScript validation can always be bypassed, because anyone could make their own submission form, and address your webpage directly from there.

Note that this entry will set a *lower* upper bound for the size of the entire POST request, thus doing exactly what you want. Also, it applies only to the POST method.

Probably it makes some sense to also set

https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size

so that an attacker may not put LOADS of data into other form elements, such as a very long string.